# Setting a link name in javascript, with PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

What I am trying to do is load a page, get a PHP variable into JavaScript, and set my element (Link) to said variable.  Then, when you click on the link, I would like it to change from open or close to close or open.  For some reason, the other solutions I have looked at don't seem to work.  What seems to be the issue with the following code?  I'm slightly confused as to why this isn't working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var state =  "<?php echo $var; ?>";
document.getElementById('open').text = state;
function toggleText(button_id) 
{
   if (document.getElementById('button_id').text == "Open") 
   {
       document.getElementById('button_id').text = "Close";
   }
   else 
   {
     document.getElementById('button_id').text = "Open";
   }
}
</script>
<a id="open" onclick="toggleText('open')" href="#"></a>
```

Thanks a lot, this is the last leg of my project, and for some reason whatever I try wont make it work.

Notice:
I have also tried instead of `.text` `.innerHTML` and it also did not work.

Comment: your script is running before the dom is ready, either use an onload event or put the script at the end of the body. Also its `innerText`,`innerHTML`,or `textContent` not `text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('buttonid').innerHTML = "<?php echo $var; ?>";
function toggleText(button) 
{
   if (button.innerHTML == "Open") 
   {
       button.innerHTML = "Close";
   }
   else 
   {
     button.innerHTML = "Open";
   }
}
</script>
<a id="buttonid" onclick="toggleText(this)" href="#"></a>
```

Put script after `</body>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the console? It's always the place to start.

Part of the problem is that you have `button_id` in single quotes. I assume that `button_id` is a variable name, and should not be in quotes. Also, you should be using `innerHTML` instead of `text`.

This should work:

```
<script type=.innerHTML/javascript">
var state =  "<?php echo $var; ?>";
document.getElementById('open').innerHTML = state;
function toggleText(button_id) 
{
   if (document.getElementById(button_id).innerHTML == "Open") 
   {
       document.getElementById(button_id).innerHTML = "Close";
   }
   else 
   {
     document.getElementById(button_id).innerHTML = "Open";
   }
}
</script>
<a id="open" onclick="toggleText('open')" href="#"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try calling `document.getElementById('open').innerText= state;` on `window.onload`

```
window.onload=function(){
     document.getElementById('open').innerText= state;
}
```

The problem could be that the dom is not ready (the page is not fully loaded) when you try to set the text property

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `<a id="button_id" onclick="toggleText('open')" href="#">open</a>`
And put the script just before the closing `</body>` tag.